# How i can set OnClickListener to button inside class that implement OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-studio, onclicklistener

I want to set OnClickListener to my button that inside alert dialog.
I am using context as a parameter but it doesn't work. The application stop working every time i touch that button here is my piece of code.
The problem button is in order_add.xml that showed in alert dialog

```
public class OnOrderClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
Context context;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    context = v.getRootView().getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View addOrderForm = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_add, null, false);
    EditText orderId = (EditText) addOrderForm.findViewById(R.id.orderIdentifierEditText);
    Button addItemToOrder = (Button) addOrderForm.findViewById(R.id.addItem);
    addItemToOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),OnClickForAddProductToOrder.class);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setView(addOrderForm)
            .setTitle(R.string.order)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.add_product_positive_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }).show();
}
```

}

Logcat :

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                         Process: com.hwp.myprototype, PID: 10753
>                                                                        android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {com.hwp.myprototype/com.hwp.myprototype.OnClickForAddProductToOrder};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1854)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1545)
>                                                                             at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4283)

I hope somebody can help me solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: post the error..

Comment: use OnOrderClickListener.this instead of context

Comment: @DivyeshPatel i already try it, but it doesn't work

Comment: Please show us the error log

Comment: is it fragment or activity

Comment: @just alright wait a minute

Comment: @DivyeshPatel its an activity

Comment: put OnClickForAddProductToOrder activity in menifest.

Comment: @JohnJoe posted

Comment: @DivyeshPatel how can i do that ?

Comment: <activity android:name=".OnClickForAddProductToOrder "
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

Comment: @DivyeshPatel alright Thank dude, your solution worked. Problem solved, i think i forgot to register that activity to manifest.

Comment: yeah. next time when you create Activity first register it in menifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add your activity to your manifest file:

```
<application
    ...>

    <activity
        android:name=".OnOrderClickListener" />

</application>
```

You do not have to implement View.OnClickListener if you are using new View.OnClickListener():

```
Button addItemToOrder = (Button) addOrderForm.findViewById(R.id.addItem);
addItemToOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),OnClickForAddProductToOrder.class);
        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

However if you want to implement View.OnClickListener then no need to use new View.OnClickListener() inside addItemToOrder.setOnClickListener(). What you have to do is this:

```
Button addItemToOrder = (Button) addOrderForm.findViewById(R.id.addItem);
addItemToOrder.setOnClickListener(this);
...

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.addItem:
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),OnClickForAddProductToOrder.class);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is Activity not defined in Manifest **OnClickForAddProductToOrder**

So Add below code in your Manifest

```
<activity
 android:name=".OnClickForAddProductToOrder"
 android:label="Add Products"
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add OnClickForAddProductToOrder activity in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Add your activity (OnClickForAddProductToOrder) in application tag in your manifest.

Example:

```
<activity android:name="OnClickForAddProductToOrder" >
```